# Get latest commits on pull request in github

Tags: git, github

I need to get the list of commits that are within the pull request, example:

I need get this:

- abc
- def
- x1
- x2
- x3
- Test 19 bill_processor

From this repository:

[image]

Comment: Cool. How are you going to do that? (Please read [ask].)

Comment: Why not use Github UI? You have to just open that pull request. It will list all the commits in that pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the commits from $PULL_REQ_ID into a new branch

```
git fetch origin pull/$PULL_REQ_ID/head:new-branch
```

and inspect the `new-branch`.